# Which HW configuration is to be used for building cross-platform FireMonkey applications?

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I've just bought a Mac Mini in order to develop Mac OS X FireMonkey applications, using Delphi XE2.

I've a main laptop under Windows Seven, which I use for development since years. But this laptop has an older (AMD TL-56 with 2GB RAM) hardware configuration than the Mac Mini (Core i5 with 4GB RAM).

What is, from your experiment, the best configuration to use? That is, where should I install Delphi XE2?

- Install IDE on the laptop, debugging remotely into the Mac? In this case, what is the best remote access tool (I wonder about Open GL remote access)? Or is the only solution to switch my monitor and keyboards to the mac?
- Or on the Mac directly - but in this case, what is the best solution: installing Delphi XE2 in a Virtual Box hosting Windows, or having a dual boot on the Mac, install Windows on it, then putting a Mac OS inside a Virtual Box?
- Any other combination?

I just like using Windows for developing - e.g. I make intensive use of Total Commander and other home-made tools. I've seen Mac computers at Embarcadero's office - I just wondered what is the best HW configuration.

I do not need answers like "try Mac OS, this is the best OS ever" - just feedback from Delphi programmers, including tips (e.g. how is working FireMonkey 3D acceleration remotely?).

Comment: My personal preference is to run 100% on my macbook laptop, using VMWare Fusion to host my Delphi XE2 installation on its VM.  Using the "Fusion" mode, I can have my XE2 IDE "right on my mac desktop" and not even need to see the windows desktop.  Plan B would be two machines, and no remote desktop.  Note that XE2 does not install onto Mac OS at all, only the platform assistant runs on OS X. SO you can't avoid Windows even if you wanted to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Setup 1**

At work, I have Delphi XE2 installed on my Windows machine with dual monitors. The second monitor is hooked up to a KVM switch that is hooked up to a Mac Mini. So, my left monitor is always Windows, and my right monitor is sometimes Mac. The keyboard and mouse are switched with the KVM.

**Setup 2**

At home, my very large monitor is for Windows, and a smaller monitor is for the Mac. Here, the monitors are exclusive, but the keyboard and mouse are still hooked up to a KVM.

In all honesty, I like this configuration better because I can start the debugger and ensure that the Mac program starts before switching over the KVM.

**Ideal Configuration?**

Ideally, though, if I had room, I'd have a keyboard and mouse for both machines, and a dedicated monitor for each.

**Remote Access**

As you probably know, there is a Remote Desktop application for the Mac that allows you to connect to your Windows computer remotely. You can also setup your Mac Mini to connect to it remotely from Windows.

**To setup your Mac for remote access from Windows**

1. On your Mac, open up System Preferences
2. From the Interenet & Wireless group, click on Sharing
3. Enable the service named "Remote Management"
4. Click the button labeled "Computer Settings..."
5. Enable the following options:

   - Show Remote Management status in menu bar
   - Anyone may request permission to control screen
   - VNC viewers may control screen with password (and enter your VNC password here)
6. From the Windows machine, use [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) client to connect and use the default connection settings.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll also look into the VMWare Fusion solution in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Marco Cantu uses a Windows box to install Delphi XE 2, and you can find details from his blog post,

http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/delphi_mac_mini.html

There is a trick to enable graphic card optimization on Mac Mini mentioned in this post too.

Comment: Nice link. There are several feedbacks from some Delphi users. I guess the VNC way will do the trick at first.